# SumoSelect not displaying checkboxes or allow (multiple or single ) selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select, sumoselect.js

SumoSelect will not display the checkboxes next to option names, nor will it properly select a single (or multiple) options.
(However, when I remove the `multiple` attribute, it is able to select a single item.)

[image: https://imgur.com/bHIlY0s]

```
<select id="w3sf-input-category" name="category[]"  multiple="multiple"></select>

$(document).ready(function (){ 
  $("#w3sf-input-category").SumoSelect({ search: true, });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My stylsheet was overriding SumoSelect's CSS.

I had... #sidebar li { padding:0; }

But I changed it to... #sidebar > li (which is limited to the first, direct decendent of the #sidebar).